# Oracle Entity Framework - mapear tablas de diferentes esquemas

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, orm

Tengo varios esquemas (ESQ1, ESQ2, ESQ3, etc) y cada esquema es para un contexto diferente, pero hay casos en los que necesito acceder a tablas de diferentes esquemas, y al momento de mapear las tablas solo logro ver las tablas del usuario con el que me autentifique.

¿Cómo hago para poder ver en el explorador de modelos las tablas de varios esquemas?

Comment: ¿De cual explorador de modelos estás hablando? ¿Cual herramienta? No estoy seguro si tu pregunta tiene que ver con entity framework en realidad, o si se trate simplemente de una cuestión de permisos en la base de datos en sí.

Comment: Como en el titulo dice, estoy trabajando con Oracle y Entity Framework, si es que sirve de algo es la versión 5 de EF, ODAC12, Oacle 10g, Vs2015, mmmm no se creo que esos datos son suficientes.

Comment: Lo que quise decir es que tal vez el problema no es *específico* a Entity Framework. Sino que tal vez es un problema mas general de base de datos, y es lo que quisiera entender mejor. Por ejemplo, si te logueas con el usuario en cuestión usando un cliente como SQL Developer, ¿tienes el mismo problema de no poder ver las tablas en los diferentes esquemas?

Comment: En mi caso trabajo con TOAD, y en el explorador de objetos veo solo las tablas de mi mismo esquema y no de otros, sin embargo si puedo poner esquema.tabla y accedo normalmente (claro, si tengo permisos), pero el dilema es desde EF como hago joins con tablas de diferentes esquemas, ya que en el modelo solo logro agregar las tablas de mi mismo esquema, y también desea agregar las tablas de otros esquemas.